# How To Avoid Opening Multiple CSV Files?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

The following code implements PSSE (Python Parallel Dynamics Simulations). This code works for me but I would like to make it better. Instead of opening numerous CSV Files for various Case Studies, is it possible to link all the information into one csv file or database to make life simpler?

Each Excel sheet has the following information: `Bus #`, `Power CHANGE`, `isload`. I tried putting another row of data from a different year but it was reading the first set of information presented. I'm trying to link all 160 CSV files (merging all CSV fiLES) I created into one, which I did, but it wasn't running.

Here's my code:

```
PSSE_LOCATION = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE33\PSSBIN"
sys.path.append(PSSE_LOCATION)
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ';' + PSSE_LOCATION

import psspy
import redirect
import csv
psspy.throwPsseExceptions = True

from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkSimpleDialog
import tkMessageBox

def quit():
    global root
    root.quit()

root= Tk()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome", "Please select case study: ")

root.fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("PSSE CASES", "*.sav"),
                                                       ("PSSE CASES", "*.sav*")))

STUDY_CASE = root.fileName

root.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),
                                                        ("All files", "*.*")))

STUDY_CASE = ('C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Documents\Base      '
              'Cases\Final\ceii_Case1_SUM_2017_5050_MMWG16PF_FINAL.sav')

LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE = 'C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Documents\CSV Files\example2.csv'

psspy.psseinit(10000)
psspy.case(STUDY_CASE)

tkMessageBox.showinfo(
    "Welcome",
    "Please select folder with year and then select desired TLA Assignment ")
root.fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("CSV FILES", "*.csv"),
                                                        ("CSV FILES", "*.csv*")))

LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE = root.fileName

# read the entire CSV into Python.
data = list(csv.reader(open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)))

# assume CSV has columns as described in the doc string
for bus,change,isload in data:
    # convert the types from string to Python numbers
    change = float(change)
    bus = int(bus)

    if isload.isdigit() and int(isload):
        psspy.bsys(1,0,[0.0,0.0],0,[],1,[bus],0,[],0,[])
        psspy.scal_2(1,0,1,[0,0,0,0,0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
        psspy.scal_2(0,1,2,[0,1,0,1,0],[change,0.0,0,-.0,0.0,-.0,0])
    else:
        exit
```

Comment: Your code has intent issues.

Comment: He intended to indent..

Comment: [Edit] your Question and add the first 3 Lines of a `CSV` File.